# Display an HTML list in reverse order with pure CSS: Bottom -> Top

Tags: html, css

I have got a HTML list:

```
<ul>
  <li> 1 </li>
  <li> 2 </li>
  <li> 3 </li>
  <li> 4 </li>
  <li> 5 </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to display it the other way around with **pure CSS**? It should look like this:

- 5
- 4
- 3
- 2
- 1

The dots are optional. Only the order is important. I know that the best solution would be to reverse the order in the HTML code, but I am looking for a tricky solution in pure CSS.

Comment: Why does it have to be reversed. Are you hard coding the <li> items? or are you using JS or something to place them in there.